# Position in mathematics after Ph.D. with publications but without recommendation letters and teaching experience

Tags: mathematics, teaching, postdocs, recommendation-letter, job

Let's say that some person has a Ph.D. in mathematics and several publications in peer-reviewed journals. After that he worked several years in another field (not directly related to mathematics). Now he is thinking about returning to mathematics. The downside is that:

1. he doesn't have any teaching experience, and
2. he can't arrange for any recommendation letters (I am not going to explain why, let's just consider it as a given for the purpose of this question).

All mathematics postdoc position announcements that I've seen so far require recommendation letters, and the vast majority of them require teaching experience. Do you know of any postdoc positions in mathematics that would make an exception?

Also, are there any other positions (in the private sector) related to mathematics that you would suggest to look for in this situation?

Comment: The obvious people to ask would be the people who are offering the jobs!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as asked, but just because you have no letters now, it doesn't mean you can't go out and get some. If you're willing and able to travel on your own dime, I'd suggest sending your work to researchers in your subfield and asking to meet.

Answer (score 6):

I can't imagine taking on someone who wasn't able to provide *any* recommendation letters, even if the candidate had several *Science* and *Nature* papers. However, I would be happy to consider strong recommendation letters from an employer in another field in combination with a very strong publication record.

Comment: Just curious, what possible value would you get from a letter from an employer in another field? That a person doesn't steal paper towels from a washroom? Why would a non-relevant recommendation letter be better than no recommendation letters at all? I genuinely don't get this.

Comment: Is the candidate a decent human being? Do they have a strong work ethic? Can they get on with other people? Can they be relied upon? Do they have grit? Do they show initiative? Do they think things through? Anything that makes a person a good employee will also help make them a good PhD candidate.

Comment: Except all the above are pretty subjective and totally irrelevant for a PhD candidate. Being in a PhD programme very often resolves to working alone in a very narrow field and reading of papers and conferences: whether the person gets along with other people or has a work ethic or dresses accordingly is not really relevant. Do you really need *someone else* to tell you that person X is a good person in an adult world?

Comment: Note that the person in the question already *has* a PhD; they aren't entering a PhD program.  I'm not sure what the phrase "PhD candidate" is meant to signify to each of you.

Comment: Incidentally, *Science* and *Nature* aren't particularly relevant journals for mathematics.

Comment: @NateEldredge they aren't particularly relevant for most fields. But they are the standard for "high profile".

Comment: @GennaroTedesco It is very relevant whether the person can function as a responsible adult and get on with other people and yes, if I can't ask someone who has worked with the person, how can I find out? I actually once made the mistake of taking on a PhD student without checking his references. He already had a PhD in another field, fair publication record, and presented well. It was a huge mistake. Never again.

Comment: @Significance You're mixing two different things. One thing is performing background check and asking for recommendation letters *suitable* to the research field the applicant deals with; one other thing is to read an un-related recommendation letter from another field that won't give you any sensible information. You don't want to trust the applicant but you want to trust someone else's opinion on the application from a different field? It seems very odd to me.

Answer (score 5):

I think complete lack of *any* sort of recommendation letters would be a serious red flag, to the extent that the application would be a non-starter (for example, at my large, state, R1 university). That is, even assuming the research record is excellent, there will be other applicants for post-docs with excellent research records, *and* with excellent letters of recommendation. In the U.S., the letters matter a lot. I gather this is not the case in some scenarios in the EU, for example, but I cannot speak authoritatively on those situations.

Comment: +1. I would add that a break of several years with, I imagine, little to none research conducted during this period will not be taken lightly by post-doc search committees.

Comment: I would like to clarify that I am well aware that recommendation letters matter a lot, and as I indicated, the lack of recommendation letters disqualifies a person even by the formal list of requirements (let alone any informal suspicions or red flags). So, my question is not about how things work in general, or in a typical case, or in most cases, or even in the vast majority of cases, but rather about the existence or non-existence of rare exceptions from these general rules.